# Flask and Tweepy oAuth error - Unable to get request token

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, flask, tweepy

So I was trying the tweepy auth using Flask framework for a practice project.. But when I try to use the OAuth using Tweepy and Flask, I am getting the 302 return stating unable to get access token.. Please help.. Code and error messages below..

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, session, request, render_template, flash
import tweepy
import flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
oauth = OAuth()
consumer_key = app.config["CONSUMER_ID"]
consumer_secret = app.config["CONSUMER_SECRET"]
access_token_key = app.config["ACCESS_KEY"]
access_token_secret = app.config["ACCESS_SECRET"]

callback_url = 'http://localhost:5000/verify'
session = dict()
db = dict()



@app.route('/')
def send_token():
    redirect_url = ""
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret, callback_url)

    try: 
        #get the request tokens
        redirect_url= auth.get_authorization_url()
        session['request_token']= (auth.request_token.key,
            auth.request_token.secret)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        print 'Error! Failed to get request token'

    #this is twitter's url for authentication
    return flask.redirect(redirect_url)


@app.route("/verify")
def get_verification():

    #get the verifier key from the request url
    verifier= request.args['oauth_verifier']

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_TOKEN, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    token = session['request_token']
    del session['request_token']

    auth.set_request_token(token[0], token[1])

    try:
            auth.get_access_token(verifier)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
            print 'Error! Failed to get access token.'

    #now you have access!
    api = tweepy.API(auth)

    #store in a db
    db['api']=api
    db['access_token_key']=auth.access_token.key
    db['access_token_secret']=auth.access_token.secret
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))

@app.route("/index")
def index():
    #auth done, app logic can begin
    api = db['api']

    #example, print your latest status posts
    return flask.render_template('tweets.html', tweets=api.user_timeline())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Error message...

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
 * Restarting with reloader
Error! Failed to get request token
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2014 20:16:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
Error! Failed to get request token
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2014 20:16:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
Error! Failed to get request token
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2014 20:16:18] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
Error! Failed to get request token
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2014 20:16:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
Error! Failed to get request token
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jul/2014 20:16:21] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
Error! Failed to get request token
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem is because the tweepy package is not updated to its latest version in Pypi.. I installed it from their github repo and it worked fine...

Comment: You should accept your own answer. It work's like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The consumer_key and consumer_secret are not read correctly from the config file. You can test it by hard coding these keys at the beginning of your code. Everything else seems fine and works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I notice that tweepy needs a bit updating.  It seems like the OauthHandler is not loading properly from the Python folder structure.  I'm still learning how the import structure works.

If I go to the installed path where Tweepy library is installed, and copy the auth.py file to my local working directory and RENAME it auth_temp.py.   Then I can access the OAuthHandler class inside it without a problem.

Comment: For python 3.X default location C:\Users\username \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages